# Automatic removal of comments when a question gets closed as "exact duplicate"

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

It happened to me several times that a comment I made was no longer there after a question was closed as an exact duplicate. It is hard for me to tell what exactly is going on because I can't see or reconstruct the comments anymore, but it seems that the mere mentioning of the word "duplicate" in a comment causes the engine to remove the entire comment as soon as the question is closed for duplication. I don't think this is the desired behavior, since any added content beyond the auto-generated comment could be useful for later visitors or the OP even after the question is closed.

I don't know if the moderators can see deleted comments with their tools, but if so, [here's an example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41165/continuous-functions-on-0-1-with-f0-f1-closed), [here's another one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37611/a-doubt-on-faltings-theorem) and [here's one on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2225/mathjax-1-1-upgrade-action-required) where it happened.

So my questions are:

> What exactly is going on and can this be corrected? If this is the desired behavior, what's the rationale behind it?

Comment: We can't see deleted comments, but I've seen this happen, and I think your guess is correct.

Comment: Thanks Qiaochu, this answered one implicit question of mine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any comments containing a *single* URL to the closed-as-duplicate-of question are automatically removed at the time of close.

Assumption being, these comments will be of the general form …

> I think this post is a duplicate of http://example.com/q/12345

… and thus not particularly useful once the close occurs; at that point the duplicate question has been edited into the post body itself as:

> Closed as duplicate of http://example.com/q/12345

Rendering such comments moot. If you have some other commentary to add about the close target question that you believe should survive the close, I recommend entering your comment thusly:

> In case anyone wonders, 2) is addressing my comment to question 12345, which is a duplicate of the present question.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications, this tells me how to avoid automatic deletion. Just to make sure I got this right: The first example I mentioned was of the form "The question and the accepted answer of the duplicate don't directly address the current question, but @xyz's post there http://example.com/q/12345#1234 answers it.", so it was deleted. Had I written "The question and the accepted answer of the duplicate http://example.com/q/12345 don't directly address the current question, but @xyz's post there http://example.com/q/12345#1234 answers it." instead, the comment would have remained?

Comment: @theo any comment with a single url containing `/12345` where the interior number is a match to the ID of the closed question will be removed at the time of close.